# Create View on Discussion Replies?

Tags: view, discussion-board

I am trying to find the number of replies posted within a date range.  I wanted to a create a view with a total column but can't seem to find the list with replies in them.  I can see the Discussions list but not replies.  How do you drill into the replies or where can those be found to be queried?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its the folder setting.  Apps like discussion boards are heavily customised and very different to custom lists/document libraries.
In the case of a Discussion Board it appears that a "folder" is created for each question with metadata containing the question etc.  The list items are actually all the replies.  So in order to view them you need to show all items without folders under the folder header in modify view.

Answer (score -1):

Try grouping by the Replies column